# How to properly configure DNS settings and Ubuntu 14.04 for postfix?

Tags: server, dns, email

I have a VPS with an assigned IP running Ubuntu 14.04 and a domain registered elsewhere. The domain's A record is pointed at the IP of the VPS. I can visit my website through the domain no problem. (And have read that I should put my domain in the server block of my nginx config).

What am I supposed to do with the nameservers and MX records parts? So far the only part of my DNS record that points to the server is the 1 A record.

I need to set up email, but even after configuring postfix, I can't send mail to it.

The contents of my /var/log/mail.log

```
Mar  1 01:32:38 postfix/sendmail[25411]: fatal: Recipient addresses must be specified on the command line or via the -t option
Mar  1 02:09:26 postfix/master[26863]: daemon started -- version 2.11.0, configuration /etc/postfix
Mar  1 02:10:56 postfix/master[26863]: terminating on signal 15
Mar  1 02:11:09 postfix/master[27272]: daemon started -- version 2.11.0, configuration /etc/postfix
Mar  1 02:19:28 postfix/master[27272]: reload -- version 2.11.0, configuration /etc/postfix
Mar  1 03:23:08 postfix/master[27272]: terminating on signal 15
Mar  1 03:23:08 postfix/master[28928]: daemon started -- version 2.11.0, configuration /etc/postfix
```

The contents of my postfix main.cf with the domain replaced with example.com

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

append_dot_mydomain = no

readme_directory = no

myhostname = example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mydestination = $myhostname localhost.$mydomain localhost
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Comment: Can you answer these two questions? **(1)** Do you have your own assigned IP?  **(2)** What did you do when you say you tried to receive your VPS hostname, that returned nothing?  Most likely #1 is yes.  Your answering to #1 will help to indicate that you know what it is and would make it easier to explain the next step.  The second question is important for moving forward also.

Comment: Configuring your VPS is an infinitely broad topic - if you have questions about configuring a specific service or something, please edit your question to be more narrow in its scope.

Comment: @L.D.James I apologize, it's the domainname that I'm not getting anything for (typed domainname in the shell and it returned (none)) the hostname is returning the machine name properly so I removed that from the tags.

Comment: @ThomasWard Edited, hope that's clearer.

Comment: @xiskus While your question and problem appears to be clear and precise to me, you might remove some of the items such as VPS, GoDaddy.  They don’t matter in setting up configuring your Ubuntu as a mail server.  I understand you thought it had something to do with your DNS configuration.  However, based on your comment, your DNS is already properly configured and working.  The `domainname` command returning `(none)`, doesn’t matter either.  I believe including more information is better than not including enough... (continued)

Comment: … (continued) But try renaming your subject to how to resolve your postfix issue.  Then add a few lines from your `/var/log/mail.log`.  I can already answer your question.  But we need to work on satisfactory changes to have it reopened.

Comment: Sure @L.D.James, lemme get to that now.

Comment: Give me an @L.D.James nudge if/when the question is reopened and I'll provide a formatted answer.  Also post a message in [Help with Askubuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/) for assistance from the community to help you to fix your question.  It appears to not be broad anymore.  If there are other problems, some of our members more experienced than me can help point out the problem with the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54706/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-xiskus).

Answer (score 0):

**The error message you are getting is a result of the email client** you are using.  It's not formatting the recipient's email address correctly.  Choose an email client such as Thunderbird, Gmail, or many Email (the default email client that comes with the android. which will format the recipient emails address correctly.  This would resolve the error that you have attached to your question.

There are also a number of Web-based email clients you can use that will work such as [Horde](https://www.horde.org/download/horde).